# number converting to other number

Tags: java, numbers, filereader

Hello I have a bit of a problem with calculating numbers from a file.

My input is the following `rawData.txt`:

> 19.95
>   5

The output however is this:

> 49.0
>  57

My code looks like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintStream;

class ReadAndWrite
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner diskScanner = null;

        diskScanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("rawData.txt"));

        PrintStream diskWriter = new PrintStream("cookedData.txt");

        double total;

        double unitPrice = diskScanner.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);

        System.out.println(unitPrice);

        int quantity = diskScanner.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);

        System.out.println(quantity);

        total = unitPrice * quantity;
        diskWriter.println(total);
        diskScanner.close();
    }
}
```

Eventually the `cookedData.txt` file contains the number `2793.0`

Please help

Comment: No problem description, voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fetching only the first character of each line - because of the charAt(0), then cast it to a double (casting char to double!!)

I can't understand what you are trying to do, but converting char to double using casting is almost always NOT what you should do.

Try using Double.parseDouble instead. see it here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

```
diskScanner.findWithinHorizon(".",0).charAt(0);
```

means that you are getting any character, because the first parameter of findWithinHorizon is a regular expression, and "." means one character. From that string you take the first char, i.e. 1. The ascii value of 1 is... 49.